# Determine the last time an Application Pool recycled

Tags: .net, application-pool, .net-services

I'm writing a .NET service that monitors application pools. based on specific triggers I'm restarting them. 
However, I do not want to restart them if the trigger occurred before they were recycled for the last time. How can I know the "last recycle time" of an app pool?

Answer (score 2):

If the [`LogEventOnRecycle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525613%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property is set, you should be able to read this information from the event log using the [`EventLog Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I went down the rabbit hole of looking through the event log and I was able to detect last when an app pool was last recycled but it was very cpu intensive because you have to read logs from the disk. I would highly suggest using

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime
```